# DFS-R RemoveDeletedFiles property cannot be set from Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-distributed-file-system, powershell-4.0

Using Powershell v4.0 as included in Windows Server 2012 R2 it is possible for me to setup DFS-R except for one detail. I cannot get the RemoveDeletedFiles property to become True. No error or warning is reported by the cmdlet, but it does not seem to have any effect. For the moment I have left the setting on False, but given that the files are generated through builds we will never restore them. It seems a waste for DFS-R to be moving these files to the ConflictAndDeleted directory.

Set-DfsrMembership -GroupName $groupName -RemoveDeletedFiles $true -FolderName $folderName -ComputerName $computerName

GroupName                   : XXX
ComputerName                : XXXYYY
FolderName                  : Folder
GroupDomainName             : name.tlc
ComputerDomainName          : name.tlc
Identifier                  : zzz
DistinguishedName           : CN=zzz,CN=yyy,CN=DFSR-LocalSettings,CN=XXXYYY,OU=ourOU,DC=name,DC=tlc
ContentPath                 : C:\Folder
PrimaryMember               : True
StagingPath                 : C:\Folder\DfsrPrivate\Staging
StagingPathQuotaInMB        : 4096
MinimumFileStagingSize      : Size256KB
ConflictAndDeletedPath      : C:\Folder\DfsrPrivate\ConflictAndDeleted
ConflictAndDeletedQuotaInMB : 4096
ReadOnly                    : False
**RemoveDeletedFiles          : False**
Enabled                     : True
DfsnPath                    : 
State                       : Normal

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue encountered today in Server 2012 R2. Seems to be a cmdlet client-side issue. If I run the above command on a Server 2012 R2 server, it fails. But if I run it on a Windows 11 client with DFS RSAT tools installed, even against the same Server 2012 R2 server, it works.